# How do I add a library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I downloaded the Gson library from http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/.
The archive contains the following jar files:

google-gson-1.3/gson-1.3-javadoc.jar
google-gson-1.3/gson-1.3.jar
google-gson-1.3/gson-1.3-sources.jar

How do I set my Eclipse to be able to use the package in my projects? Where do I put the documentation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right Click on the project, Build Path->Add External Archives

Comment: And you can also link the javadoc :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the youtube link which answers this question. it shows how to step by step add gson to Java. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzdIcbnnwSA

1)Add google-gson-1.3/gson-1.3.jar as external library

2) click on the new added library and add  google-gson-1.3/gson-1.3-sources.jar  to source attachment

3) click on the new added library and add  javadoc google-gson-1.3/gson-1.3-javadoc.jar to javadoc location.