# How to Include and Use GSON library in Eclipse project

Tags: json, jsp, gson

I'm from the PHP background, so pardon my noobness. I'm required to use JSON in one of my projects and I cannot, for the life of me, determine how to import and use the GSON library.

I followed [Adding library to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759168/how-do-i-add-a-library-in-eclipse) and [Using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848601/arraylistobject-json) threads but for some reason my code isn't working.

**The aim is to pass an `ArrayList` object back as a JSON array so that I can use Jquery (inside Ajax success function) to iterate over it.**

But when I use the following (This is not a `class`, simply a jsp file which connects to database, pulls some info, and stores it in an `ArrayList`):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
String kw = request.getParameter("key");
try {
java.sql.Connection con;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abcd", "root", "pass");
st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT t.tckid FROM ticket t  WHERE t.tckid LIKE '%"+kw+"%'"); 
ArrayList<String> tickets = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) {
        String TCKTID = rs.getString(1);
        tickets.add(TCKTID);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();        
Gson gson = new Gson(); // this is giving me Gson cannot be resolved to a type
```

So of what I can gather, the `Gson` class didn't get imported at all. Is there a way to verify the successful import of the library? Or do I also need to use some `import ***` code on the top of the file?

Comment: do you have this jar file https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ if you are using Gson

Comment: @Kerppag Yes, there were 3 jar files in that zip, but I only imported `gson-2.2.4.jar` file. That's why I was asking if there was a way to verify whether the import was successful or not

Comment: did you paste the jar file to your web-inf/lib folder?

Comment: @Kerppag No, I put the `gson-2.2.4.jar` file on the desktop. Then I right-clicked my project in eclispe, choose "build path->configure build path" then clicked on "Add External JARs", navigated to the jar file and finally clicked "OK"

Comment: paste it to your web-inf/lib folder

Comment: and use this import com.google.gson.Gson;

Comment: Ok did that, but still no luck

Comment: could you post your class code

Comment: Well, it's not a class. Simply a jsp page in which I'm pulling some data from the database and trying to send back the result in json format

Comment: i seeee! so that is a scriptlet? <% ... %> like this?

Comment: hmm.you should know the MVC pattern with web. please avoid using scriptlets but you can import it with <%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>

Comment: You're a life saver! If you put that up as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it for you. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not importing the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) package in your current `JSP`.

```
<%

Gson gson=new Gson();

%>
```

importing in `JSP`

```
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>
```

but please keep in mind to avoid using scriptlets in your `JSP`[MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to separate the server  side with the client side actions/purpose. if you want to display values coming from the database you could always use [JSTL](https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=H3_oU_G7BYqK8QewmIHYDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=jstl) and using different scopes(request scope,session scope, etc).

Comment: Sorry, couldn't upvote as it requires 15 rep EDIT: Voila! I do now..+1

Comment: well it's fine, as long as it solved your problem, thats fine :)